# Set different values for non-current and current statuslines

Tags: vimrc, neovim, statusline, set

When vim is split into different panes horizontally, each pane has its own statusline. It's easy to **highlight** the statuslines differently based on current and non-current panes. BUT, I cannot figure out how to set different values for `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC`. Only the former is recognized by vim/neovim.

My plan is replace the values of non-active statuslines with em-dashes, making it look like a line-divider between panes. The active pane will have a conventional statusline with the a filepath, columns, row, etc.

How do you set separate values for them? Is this possible? Suggestions?

**Bonus question:** how can you repeat a single char through a statusline?

Comment: `StatusLine` and the NC variant are highlight groups; if you are referring to the `'statusline'` option, Im afraid there is only one.

Comment: correct, and there is no need for another option. You would set the statusline option to a function that checks what is the current window and returns the content for each statusline. This is basically what vim-airline does

Comment: Trying to make Christian's comment more noob-friendly: you can tell vim to show what you want based on the current status of split with `BufEnter` and `BufLeave` autocommands. Suggesting looking into from @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: Thanks, all insightful answers! I see now that this is possible, albeit a little cumbersome. I'll need some actual understanding of vimscript, so I've started reading "Learning Vimscript the hard way". I'll post the solution once I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

To change the divider for the none current window you can do this with (look up `:help fillchars`):

```
set fillchars=stlnc:-
```

To change some content depending on whether it is the current or none current window:

```
function SomeText(nr)
    let activebuffer = (a:nr == win_getid()) ? "Active Window" : "None Current Window"
    let buf_type = &buftype
    return activebuffer." & ".buf_type
endfun
function MyStatusLineWrapper() abort
    let startup_win_id = win_getid()
    let s = "%{SomeText(".startup_win_id.")} ".startup_win_id
    return s
endfun

set statusline=%!MyStatusLineWrapper()
```